# Open relative links from markdown files in a cloud folder?

Tags: google-drive, cloud-storage, markdown, web-application

I’ve uploaded a structured folder with .md files to Google Drive. It’s an export from Joplin, with some files linking to images, other .md’s and other files, all within subfolders.

Locally, I’ve tested with Typora and it can follow the links. In other words, the links are not dependent on Joplin.

I want to copy the folder to Google drive or other cloud
service, and yet be able to similarly follow markdown links around.

In drive, I  tried the markdown  apps "Markee markdown editor", and "Markdown preview". Both couldn't. I tried StackEdit, but it seems Google has revoked its authorization.

Can you suggest a Drive/other cloud/cloud+app combo solution?